# Why does my php 'else' displays both at once?

Tags: php

I have this php code which determines if the user has already voted or not.

`$row_content['Vote_Who']` contains a list of all users who have previously voted, and is formatted like "User_1 User_2 User_3"

`$_SESSION['Username']` is the current username of the user who is signed in. Yes this works, as I have called it elsewhere on the page.

```
<?php if(strpos($row_content['Vote_Who'], $_SESSION['Username']) !== false){?>
    <input type="button" value="Thanks for voting!">
<?php }
else{ ?>
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $row_content['Votes']?>: Vote Up! ▲" width="75px">
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="vote">
<?php } ?>
```

But when I see the result in the web browser, both the buttons are displayed at once.

How can I fix that?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Image that proves both buttons display at the same time
[image]

UPDATE:
Full code section:

```
<?php
    if ($totalRows_content > 0){
        do {?>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="75px" height="75px" align="right">
                        <img src="<?php echo $row_content['User_Pic']?>" width="50px" height="50px">
                        <br />
                        <?php echo $row_content['Author']?>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <h2>
                            <?php echo $row_content['Title']?>
                        </h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td style="vertical-align:top">
                        <h3>
                            <?php echo $row_content['Content']?>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </h3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="150px" style="vertical-align:top">
                        <img src="<?php echo $row_content['Picture']?>" style="max-width:150px; max-height:100px">
                        <h3>
                            <?php echo $row_content['Published']?>
                        </h3>
                        <br />
                        <?php if(isset ($_SESSION['Username'])){?>
                            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" name="vote">
                                <input type="text" hidden="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $row_content['ID']?>">
                                <input type="text" hidden="hidden" name="votes_up" value="<?php echo ($row_content['Votes'] + 1)?>">
                                <?php if(strpos($row_content['Vote_Who'], $_SESSION['Username']) !== false){?>
                                    <input type="button" value="Thanks for voting!">
                                <?php }
                                else{ ?>
                                    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $row_content['Votes']?>: Vote Up! ▲" width="75px">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="vote">
                                <?php } ?>
                            </form>
                            <a href="comments.php?ID=<?php echo $row_content['ID']?>">
                                <input type="button" value="See Comments">
                            </a>
                        <?php } 
                        else{?>
                            <?php echo $row_content['Votes']?> Votes - You must be signed in to vote
                        <?php }?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?php }while ($row_content = mysql_fetch_assoc($content));}
        else{?>
            there is nothing
        <?php }
        ?>
```

Comment: is php running at all? onlh reason i can think of is you're just opening as html

Comment: did you enable error_reporting ?

Comment: @user5328504 he wouldn't be able to display values from the session if PHP wasn't running.

Comment: then ... i've got nothing. But you have to admit it was a good idea for a trully ilogical (at leeast as presented) problem

Comment: Where does `$row_content` come from? Is the if/else block inside a loop by any chance? I don't see anything in the code included in the question that would make both buttons show up.

Comment: @user2860957 The line of code which you have quoted me is for the text in the button. Which displays correctly. [1001: Vote Up!▲]

Comment: @Don'tPanic , The code is contained within a loop which prints a table row for every record in the sql table

Comment: @user2860957 I have added a screenshot to my post which shows that both buttons are displayed at the same time.

Since this user has already voted, I only want the "Thanks for voting" to be displayed

(Ignore the comments button)

Comment: @user2860957 I've added the complete code section

Comment: @user2860957 I've just solved my problem, see the answer for details

Answer (score 0):

The problem was where I'd used the operator of

```
!==
```

when what I should have used was

```
!=
```

Example:

```
strpos($row_content['Vote_Who'], $_SESSION['Username']) != false
```

Thanks to everyone who offered assistance with this issue.